# youtube-dl, download files which has subtitle

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to download videos of a channel which has subtitle. There are more than thousands files, but only a few has subtitle.

`youtube-dl --all-subs -ciw -o "./tmp/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVW0Xz85qSA&list=PLElG6fwk_0UmBgC02jKJePx`

If I can run a command after every url download, it can be good enough. In this case I will check existence of any subtitle file and decide to keep it or remove it.

maybe `--exec` is good, but it did not work for me as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be probably done in more elegant way.
But it works for me.

First extract urls that have subtitles (replace "playlist_url" with actual url of a playlist, of course)

```
youtube-dl --write-sub -ij playlist_url | jq -r ".subtitles" \
| grep -Eo "v=[^\&]+" | sort -u > urls.txt \
&& sed -i -e s7^7https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?7 urls.txt
```

and then download those files with a batch input

```
youtube-dl -cia urls.txt
```

* notice that proper playlist_url for channel adress you provided is "https://www.youtube.com/user/SonechkoProject/videos"

Comment: it did not work for me. I tested it for this playlist url `//www.youtube.com/watch?v=iy9J81i-Y-k&list=PLElG6fwk_0UmBgC02jKJePxzFRne4OCHy`. it includes a video with subtitle. I see json output. it includes ".subtitles", but urls.txt is empty at the end. I even removed grep, sort, and sed commands. but the result is the same.

Comment: Your address is single video address with playlist attached. You need to wrap it with quotation marks since there is entity in it.